# Equivalent of 'git bisect run' for mercurial?

Tags: mercurial, bisect

[`git bisect run`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect#_bisect_run) conveniently bisects a given range of revisions with a script run on each revision whose exit status is used to determine whether it is good, bad or broken.

`hg bisect` does not seem to offer this automatic ability. I need to manually mark each revision as either good or bad. Is there an extension or script that provides a functionality comparable to `git bisect run` for mercurial?

Answer (score 0):

Read `hg help bisect` by eyes. Note `-c CMD` option. Use it